# Remove marker from Gmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to integrate Gmaps in my application, drawing front-end using ExtJs 6.0, and I want to show and hide some user position inside the map.

Adding a `marker` with user position is quite easy (though I get some strange `Cannot read property 'getBounds' of undefined`, but I think that's not a big deal).

On the other side, removing a `marker` it's revealing a little bit more complicated than I thought.

I've read some questions on Stack and Google's Documentation on add/remove markers, and I understand that the "right" way to do it is calling

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

But I got a strange behaviour: the marker won't disappear and remains on the map.

**This** is how I add the marker on the map:

```
addMarker : function(record) {
        var me = this;
        var map = me.lookupController().lookupReference('map');
        var latitude = record.get('latitude');
        var longitude = record.get('longitude');
        var description = record.get('fullName');

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            lat: latitude, 
            lng: longitude,
            title : description
        });

        me.lookupViewModel().get('techniciansMaker').push(marker);
        map.addMarker(marker);
    }
```

And **this** is how I try to remove marker from the map:

```
removeMarker : function(record){
        var me = this;
        var markers = me.lookupViewModel().get('techniciansMaker');

        for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
            var m = markers[i];
            if (markers[i].getTitle() == record.get('fullName')){
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                Ext.Array.remove(markers, markers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I'm keeping markers in a list to recognize which one I have to delete.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong....

**EDIT - SOLVED**

I figured out by myself that I was pointing to `map container` and not the `map` itself. 
Calling `map.gmap` did the trick.

Comment: did u check if that condition before removing the marker is passed?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @jkris yes, the condition is satisfied

Answer (score 0):

When using [Ext.ux.GMapPanel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.ux.GMapPanel.html) you should not create the marker yourself with `new google.maps.Marker()`. Instead [addMarker](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/src/GMapPanel.js.html#line89) will do this and make `listeners:{click:...}` work on the marker. You pass the config to addMarker which returns a marker object:

```js
markerConfig = {
        lat: latitude, 
        lng: longitude,
        title : description
}
marker = mapPanel.addMarker(markerConfig)

// hide the marker
marker.setMap(null)

// show it again
marker.setMap(mapPanel.gmap)
```

This allows you to remove the marker and gets rid of that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBounds' of undefined`.